# Firebase FCM not being caught by the onMessage()

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm having trouble implementing FCM into my react native application. The documentation isn't great at all so have to come here for some assistance. I set up a cloud function that will send a notification to the given token. Only problem is, there aren't any errors, and the function doesn't send a notification.

**Cloud Function**

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.https.onCall((fcmToken) => {
  console.log(fcmToken);
  console.log("in the func");
  const message = {
    notification: {
      title: "850",
      body: "2:45",
    },
    token: fcmToken,
  };

  // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
  // registration token.
  admin.messaging().send(message)
      .then((response) => {
      // Response is a message ID string.
        console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error sending message:", error);
      });
  // See documentation on defining a message payload.
});
```

**React Native Listener**

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async (remoteMessage) => {
    Alert.alert('A new FCM message arrived!', JSON.stringify(remoteMessage))
})
```

**Invoking the Cloud Function**

```
const token = await messaging().getToken()
functions()
  .httpsCallable('sendNotification')(token)
  .then(async (response) => {
    console.log(response)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

Comment: My dashboard says there have been 48 sent messages, but 0 received. So I'm assuming there's something wrong with the token being given, although I'm not sure what could possibly be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think u should not use it in useeffect.

I was using that on index.js before Appregistry

```
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
async function onMessageReceived(message) {

 
  console.log("background message: " + JSON.stringify(message.data));
}
 messaging().onMessage(onMessageReceived);
 
function HeadlessCheck({ isHeadless }) {
  if (isHeadless) {
    // App has been launched in the background by iOS, ignore
    return null;
  }

  return <App />;
}



 AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () =>HeadlessCheck );
```

Like that

Comment: I don't think this is correct because this is straight from the docs.

Comment: u can check usage page at rnfirebase.io. there is multiple usage. my usage under the background notification. but it still works fine.